# How to call a function properly as part of a query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

I'm new to the calling stored functions and stored procedures in queries.  Can someone help me understand how to better call a stored function than I do below.  It seems like there must be a more realistic, logical way so the code flows.  This seems a bit crazy.

```
SELECT        SUM(TotalAmt) AS [Total Amount]
FROM            dbo.fDataamount('1', @startdate, @enddate, '1', '1', 'Total', 'Total', 'Total', 'Total', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1') AS fDataamount_1
WHERE        (DataID = 55)
```

Comment: Are you wondering just about syntax? That looks like the standard way to call a stored function to me. That said, I would probably suggest refactoring your logic if it really takes 14 parameters to perform the function...

Comment: If you could post your fDataamount function, then we could help refactor it.  Perhaps with sample data and desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Is your query not working? Or are you looking for a better way of writing it.

If it's not working, check to make sure it's a table-valued function.

I would also look at how often that function is being used. I prefer to use functions only if  I can consolidate code that's being used across multiple stored procedures for easier maintaining.

If the function is only used in this one stored procedure consider creating the data set in a temp table or CTE and reference that instead.

What I can gleam from your query, you're essentially taking the sum of a column out of a table that is returned from the function. Why bother using a function at all? You can take that logic out of the function and put it directly in the query.